# Setting different recto/verso margins size (geometry) on this example

Tags: margins, double-sided, geometry

---

## CONTEXT.

Because of specific University requirements (1), I had to use this nice code found on *tex.stackexchange* https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96366/50507 written by *[David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle)*, that was fitting perfectly with my needs so far.

(1)  *The requirements are listed on that question, please follow the link, I don't want to make a duplicate. It also explains the `oneside` document article.*

Therefore, given the linked code, let's consider it as my **Minimum Working Example :**

```
\documentclass[oneside]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\def\a{One two three four \stepcounter{enumi}\roman{enumi} five six. }
\def\b{\a\a\par\a\a\a Red green blue yellow black white. }
\def\c{\b\b\par\b\b\b\b\b\par\b\b\b\par\b\b\b\par\b}
\makeatletter
\def\@oddhead{ODD PAGE\hfill\thepage}

\long\def\grabfirst#1#2\@@{\toks@{#2}\xdef\insertlist{\the\toks@}#1}
\let\old@outputpage\@outputpage
\def\@outputpage{%
\ifx\insertlist\@empty
\shipout\vbox to\@colht {\vss}%
\else
\begingroup
\setbox\@outputbox\vbox to\@colht {%
\expandafter\grabfirst\insertlist\@@
}%
\def\@oddhead{\thepage(x)  \hfill EVEN PAGE}
\old@outputpage
\addtocounter{page}{-1}%
\endgroup
\fi
\old@outputpage}

\gdef\insertlist{}
\long\def\insertpic#1{\g@addto@macro\insertlist{{#1}}}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\c
\insertpic{%
\rule{1cm}{2cm}
\captionof{figure}{a picture}}
\c
\begin{figure}[t]
this\\
is\\
a\\
t figure

\caption{zzz}
\end{figure}

\c
\begin{figure}[p]
this\\
is\\
a\\
p figure

\caption{zzz}
\end{figure}

\c
\insertpic{%
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\captionof{figure}{a picture}}

\c
\end{document}
```

---

## THE PROBLEM.

My aim is  to set up different margins on recto pages and verso pages, for example :

- on recto : left = 3cm, right = 3cm, top = 3cm, bottom = 3cm (let's say it's the default, given on the full report, except on verso when they occur)
- on verso only (when they occur): left = 2cm, right = 2cm, top = 1.5cm, bottom = 1.5cm

The problem is that some of the pictures (and tables) are too wide for the global margin used for the entire code, thus for the verso as well.

---

## MY QUESTION.

I don't see how I can modify the margins geometry of one side (verso) without modifying the other side (recto) and not breaking the given code. I would be most grateful if you could help me with that.

---

## ADDITIONAL NOTE.

Please note that it was not the nature of my question - my first question was simply to use different geometry on recto and verso - the linked solution worked very fine for me so far except for these margins.

*However* if there is no way to set up different margin on recto and verso with this code, I would be most grateful if you could propose another solution with the same numbering requirements.

> **SUGGESTIONS regarding the question format?**
>
> As I didn't received any answers yet, should you have any suggestion to help me presenting better the issue
> that I am facing, so that I could get more easily a solution, please
> do not hesitate to let me know in comments.  Shall I propose another bounty ? What should I do to find some hints about that topic ? Thank you again for your
> attention.

Comment: Onesided documents have no `verso`pages.

Comment: @Johannes_B : We just had the same conversation with another user (comments were deleted by both of us). Please read the university requirements given in the linked page, explaining why it's "onesided" (I had the same requirements actually). I am open to any code suggestion you may have for such requirements, I would be very pleased if you had a "cleaner" suggestions for that. Otherwise, they are still some "recto/verso" pages thanks to this code, and I am still looking for a solution =). Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: There is no link in the question you refer to.

Comment: @enigmator I see no link to the university requirements.

Comment: @egreg Requirements are written in the linked question, as written above. I don't understand from where the problem is coming from by your side. (the link again : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96343/output-two-sided-but-only-on-recto-page-occasional-images-on-verso). It's weird that you can't see the link of the other tex.stackexchange question, I can see it by my side.

Comment: Then  please provide the link in this question. I see no link either. Plus the linked page has nothing to do with layout.

Comment: @enigmator I see your link and it links to the correct answer. I can't help you though.

Comment: @daleif : Please check my edited topic, There might be a displaying issue for some of you. Since the linked page has everything to do with layout and my topic, are you trolling me?. at:Juri Robl : thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: @enigmator, it was the `counter` part in the page title, I think that is a site error.

Comment: @enigmator, plus I'm refering to the university requirements. I'd like to see those from the source not another question on this site.

Comment: I do not see any margin requirements on the page you refer to.

Comment: @daleif The university requirements are all mentioned and given in the linked topic. I am not going to copy and past them, otherwise this would make the current topic a duplicate. Furthermore, this is not the object of my question (except if they are no other solutions than reforging a completely new report that would fit with requirements + margins issues).

Comment: `oneside` is not a document class. The document class is `article`. `geometry` lets you temporarily change the page geometry and restore it afterwards. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @cfr : yes, my mistake.

Comment: @enigmator So is `geometry` an option?

Comment: @cfr I didn't manage to make it work with Geometry. I wish it could be a systematic settings and not to have to set "by hand" the geometry. This would be great if we could set the geometry for the recto pages and for the verso in the settings of them.

Comment: I'm just curious, in case no answer appears, if that is possible in ConTeXt (you might want to add the tag in case that calls ConTeXt beasts on this site).

Comment: @Manuel what do you mean by ConTeXt exactly ? I don't know what it refers to.

Comment: @enigmator ConTeXt is an alternative to LaTeX, but it comes, by default, with many, many more options and, may be, it's possible there semi-out of the box. I would add the tag `context`. You can also ask in the [mailing list](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Mailing_Lists).

Answer (score 1):

One can do this by setting margin for (recto) odd pages using geometry, for example

```
\usepackage[margin={3cm,4cm}]{geometry}
```

or

```
\usepackage[margin=3cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
```

and then change localy the settings of (verso) even pages by

```
\def\@outputpage{%
\ifx\insertlist\@empty
\shipout\vbox to\@colht {\vss}%
\else
\begingroup
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-1cm}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-1.5cm}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{2cm}
\addtolength{\@colht}{3cm}
\setbox\@outputbox\vbox to\@colht {%
\expandafter\grabfirst\insertlist\@@
}%
\def\@oddhead{\thepage(x)  \hfill EVEN PAGE}
\old@outputpage
\addtocounter{page}{-1}%
\endgroup
\fi
\old@outputpage}
```