# number one page every two pages

Tags: page-numbering

Hi I have to write an article and I want to put the figures on the back of the pages where the text is. So I thought I just had to always put a blank page between every text page so I can put my figures  there.
The only problem is that i dont want to put page numbers on the sides where my figures are.
Do you have any idea what command you have to use?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I don't think this is very good strategy. You would print empty pages anyway or you have to make some pdfmerge/pdfselect after production of the output pdf to remove the blank dummy pages. In addition -- if you know you have to use a `\clearpage` or `\newpage`, you could place the figure right afterwards, without letting it float away (i.e. omit the figure environment)

Comment: what I do is use the command \newpage I put my figure on it and then I use \newpage again. But then the page where the figure is will also have a number, and that is what  i'm trying to avoid. For the blank pages won't have any because if I print it recto-verso they will be the blank verso of the page just before.

Comment: you are looking for something like this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96343/output-two-sided-but-only-on-recto-page-occasional-images-on-verso

Comment: This is a very strange requirement. Unless you are asked to do this by someone else, rethink your approach. LaTeX layout is the result of decades of consensus by professional typesetters, going against what it does by default needs a *powerful* argument.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from whether this is a good idea, you probably want to wrap this in a command, and use `figure` to avoid ugly page breaks:

```
\def\figpage#1{%
    \begin{figure}[p!]
    #1%
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    \end{figure}
}

\figpage{\includegraphics{figure.mps}}
```

Beware of this code; I've not tested it.  But this should give you your figures on its own page, which will not advance the page numbers.  It will only work if you've got figures on every recto page, though; if you don't, there won't be a figure page, and you'll just get a normal verso page which will advance your page number.

If you know where your page breaks will be already, just do the following on your figure pages:

```
\addtocounter{page}{-1}
\thispagesyle{empty}
```

That will remove any header or footer, so that the page number won't be displayed, and prevent the page number from being incremented.

If you want some header or footer information displayed on these pages, you'll need to define a separate pagestyle for them  See the documentation for `fancyhdr` for an easy way to do this.

Comment: I am not sure this prevents the figure to float away to be placed on some other page

Comment: Will it not float to the next page by default?

Comment: I am not sure. I never use floats, so my comment is rather a safety question then based on knowledge. You should try with some 'real' document

Comment: At least use `p!` so that the figure won't float away if it is too small.

Comment: I forgot about !; edited.