# Combine onesided and twosided layout in one document

Tags: page-breaking, double-sided

I'm confused on how to do the following: The first 50 Pages (except the cover) should be printed only on the right side of my two page document. The last 100 Pages (Appendix) should be printed front and back. I also would like to see those empty left pages in the generated pdf, so i cant hand it over to the printer.
Any suggestions?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You kill many trees, you know, regarding empty pages ;-)

Comment: I would split the documeent into two completely different volumes, One for the actual thesis, one volum for the supplementatry material (appendix). Might be a bit hard, if a lot of crossreferencing should be done.

Comment: related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96343/output-two-sided-but-only-on-recto-page-occasional-images-on-verso/

Comment: Should the blank page numbers 'count'? That is, should the 2nd odd page be page 2 or page 3?

Answer (score 5):

here is a solution

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\let\old@outputpage\@outputpage
\def\@outputpage{\old@outputpage\shipout\vbox{}}
\@twosidefalse \@mparswitchfalse
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-70]

\makeatletter
\let\@outputpage\old@outputpage
\@twosidetrue  \@mparswitchtrue
\makeatother

\lipsum[1-70]

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. I guess we still need to find out from the OP what to do about the blank ("verso") pages: Should they be numbered (maybe invisibly) or not? Put differently, should the first fifty nonblank pages be numbered "1, 2, 3, ..." or "1, 3, 5, ..."? Let's hope he/she clarifies this matter.

Answer (score 3):

Here is version that uses @touhami's hook, but provides more automation:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@appendix
\g@addto@macro\appendix{\@appendixtrue}
\let\ltx@outputpage\@outputpage
\def\@outputpage{%
  \if@appendix
    \@twosidetrue\@mparswitchtrue
    \ltx@outputpage
  \else
    \@twosidefalse\@mparswitchfalse
    \ltx@outputpage\shipout\vbox{}% or \vbox{\stepcounter{page}} if you want to have the empy pages "silently" numbered
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\newpage
\appendix
\lipsum
\end{document}
```