# Error using tikzexternalize when placing an image on the verso page

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, double-sided, tikz-external

I am preparing a thesis in the same manner as detailed in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96343/output-two-sided-but-only-on-recto-page-occasional-images-on-verso).

Namely, I am looking to write a thesis with the text appearing on the right (odd) page, and images appearing on the left (even) page.

The answer provided to the previous question works as desired for all images. However, if I use a `tikzpicture` environment and well as the externalization library I receive the following error:

```
Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape 
-halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "main-figure0" 
"\def\tikzexternalrealjob{main}\input{main}"' did NOT result in a 
usable output file 'main-figure0'
```

The externalization will work as long as the `tikz` code is not included in the provided `insertpic` command. However, then all the images will always appear on the right-hand page, which is not desired.

From my basic understanding of `TeX`, I believe the source of the error may be to do with the way the `insertpic` command seems to be collecting up the images before shipping them out, which I assume is somehow conflicting with the externalization library.

My question is then, is there any way to use the `insertpic` command and the externalization library together?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
% See: <https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96343/>
\makeatletter
\def\@oddhead{ODD PAGE\hfill\thepage}

\long\def\grabfirst#1#2\@@{\toks@{#2}\xdef\insertlist{\the\toks@}#1}
\let\old@outputpage\@outputpage
\def\@outputpage{%
\ifx\insertlist\@empty
\shipout\vbox to\@colht {\vss}%
\else
\begingroup
\setbox\@outputbox\vbox to\@colht {%
\expandafter\grabfirst\insertlist\@@
}%
\def\@oddhead{\thepage A  \hfill EVEN PAGE}
\old@outputpage
\addtocounter{page}{-1}%
\endgroup
\fi
\old@outputpage}

\gdef\insertlist{}
\long\def\insertpic#1{\g@addto@macro\insertlist{{#1}}}

\makeatother

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}

Some text here.
A figure will be on the facing page.

\insertpic{
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[red] (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For me this error is produced on the first run only.  On subsequent runs the code compiles fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the error on subsequent runs. I'm using a fully updated TeX Live installation. I should note that the main PDF file will be created as intended even on the first run, but the images will not be externalized on any run, which is causing the error.